# Facebook OpenGraphActionDialog ignores the "is user generated image" flag

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I'm currently trying to create a FacebookDialog that posts with a local image. I am able to create the dialog with the image and post it, but the "user generated" flag appears to be ignored.

What I'm getting is this:
[image: facebook small image]

...when it should look like this:

[image]

The `NativeAppCallContentProvider` has been set in the manifest and the "User Generated Photos" option has been enabled in the Open Graph Action

Here is the code I'm using...

```
OpenGraphObject ogObject = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("app:objectName");
ogObject.setTitle("title");
ogObject.setDescription("description");

// Prepare the action
OpenGraphAction ogAction = OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost("app:actionName");
ogAction.setProperty("objectName", ogObject);

// Prepare the image
Bitmap imageBitmap = ...
List<Bitmap> photoBitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
photoBitmaps.add(imageBitmap);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, ogAction, "objectName")
    .setImageAttachmentsForObject("objectName", photoBitmaps, true) // user generated is set 'true' 
    .build();
mUiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

**edit:**

I ran the Scrumptious sample app from the Facebook SDK and it's the exactly the same. The "user_generated" property is set to "true", but the picture still appears as a thumbnail.

Comment: How big are these images (width x height)? Have you tried setting the image attachment on the action rather than the object?

Comment: @MingLi I've tried images of variable height, but they have all been larger than 480x480. I initially received an error stating that the images were too small. Setting the image on the action requires `URLs` or `JSONObjects`, which I do not have.

Comment: Interesting, you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs with repro steps, and one of our support engineers will have a look.

Comment: @MingLi Actually, I tried `.setImageAttachmentsForAction(photoBitmaps, true)` and while an image appears in the dialog preview, there is no image at all in the post itself. Could that be related?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am testing using a facebook test user. Make sure you have the user generated photo checkbox in your app dashboard checked.

I wonder if you need to have your action approved by Facebook before you can use the user generated feature?

Comment: I'm afraid it is a bug. The Scrumptious sample app that comes with the Facebook SDK doesn't work either.

Comment: Any news on this? This is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Nope. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/894961473857663